# SQL Server : query for Json string column

Tags: json, sql-server

I have a table with 3 columns and Sample data looks like this:

```
 +------------+--------------------+---------------------------+
| Address    | Type               | setting                    |
+------------+--------------------+---------------------======-+
|   All.staff| permission         | Provider1+AllowPost+true   |
|   All.staff| permission         | Provider1+Allowdelete+False|
|   All.staff| permission         | Provider1+AllowEdit+true   |
|     manager| permission         | Provider2+AllowPost+False  |
|     manager| permission         | Provider2+AllowEdit+true   |
+------------+--------------------+----------------------------+
```

I want to query that table such that the result will be a JSON object in 3rd column and that's needs to be split by "+" sign and it is one row per Address. Group being here Address, Type combination. I want to use JSON object functions to cater this output, any one please help would be appreciated

The expected output

```
+------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------
| Address    | Type       | setting                                                              
+------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------
|All.staff   | permission |[{provider:provider1, key:AllowPost,value: true},{provider:provider1,key:Allowdelete,value:False},{provider:provider1,Key:AllowEdit,value:true}] 
|manager     | permission |[{ provider:provider2,key:AllowPost,value: false},{provider:provider2,Key:AllowEdit,value:true}]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work? I **assume** you're using SQL Server 2016+ and so your failed to implement `FOR JSON`? What error message did you get, or why weren't the results as you expected? If you're not using 2016+, then SQL Server is not the right tool for this task, as older versions don't support JSON.

Comment: First mistake: Keeping two values instead of one in each row in the settings column.

Comment: Is the maximum number of values in `setting` always two? So it is always `key+boolean`?  Or can there be more?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, by Zohar Peled, you need to fix your design first, which can quite easily be done with `PARSENAME`.

```
--Create some sample data

CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (SomeID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                            [Address] varchar(20),
                            [Type] varchar(20),
                            Setting varchar(100));

GO
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (Address,
                           Type,
                           Setting)
VALUES ('All.staff','permission','AllowPost+true'),
       ('All.staff','permission','Allowdelete+False'),
       ('All.staff','permission','AllowEdit+true'),
       ('manager','permission','AllowPost+False'),
       ('manager','permission','AllowEdit+true');
GO

--Add a new column
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD SettingValue bit; --True/false so use a bit
GO

--Split out values
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET Setting = PARSENAME(REPLACE(Setting,N'+',N'.'),2),
    SettingValue = CASE PARSENAME(REPLACE(Setting,N'+',N'.'),1) WHEN 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

After that, you can use `FOR JSON` in a subquery to get the results you are after:

```
SELECT YT.Address,
       YT.Type,
       (SELECT J.Setting AS [key],
               CASE J.SettingValue WHEN 1 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS [value]
        FROM dbo.YourTable J
        WHERE J.Address = YT.Address
          AND J.Type = YT.Type
        FOR JSON PATH) AS setting
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
GROUP BY YT.Address,
         YT.Type;
```

Answer (score 0):

This operation can be achieved using pure TSQL without any schema changes or use of JSON functions in a couple of distinct steps to achieve.

**Step 1: Convert `setting` to JSON format**

First, the `setting` needs to be 'converted' to the JSON-style output.  To establish how to split the `setting`, the position of the `+` is evaluated using `CHARINDEX`:

```
CHARINDEX('+', setting)
```

If this returns a value higher than 0, then it is possible to split the string.  This is achieved using `SUBSTRING`:

```
SUBSTRING(setting, 0, CHARINDEX('+', setting))
-- Returns 'AllowPost'

SUBSTRING(setting, CHARINDEX('+', setting) + 1, LEN(setting) - CHARINDEX('+', setting) + 1)
-- Returns 'true'
```

Next you can concatenate the strings together with the surrounding syntax to build the JSON output:

```
CONCAT('{ key:', SUBSTRING(setting, 0, CHARINDEX('+', setting)), ',value: ', SUBSTRING(setting, CHARINDEX('+', setting) + 1, LEN(setting) - CHARINDEX('+', setting) + 1), ' }')
-- Returns '{ key:AllowPost,value: true }'
```

Finally build this into your `SELECT` with a `CASE` statement to only perform the string manipulation when the column definitely contains the `+` symbol:

```
SELECT  *,
        CASE
          WHEN CHARINDEX('+', setting) > 0 THEN CONCAT('[{ key:', SUBSTRING(setting, 0, CHARINDEX('+', setting)), ',value: ', SUBSTRING(setting, CHARINDEX('+', setting) + 1, LEN(setting) - CHARINDEX('+', setting) + 1), ' }')
          ELSE ''
        END AS JsonOutput
  FROM  MyTable
```

This outputs:

```
Address     Type        setting             JsonOutput
All.staff   permission  AllowPost+true      { key:AllowPost,value: true }
All.staff   permission  Allowdelete+False   { key:Allowdelete,value: False }
All.staff   permission  AllowEdit+true      { key:AllowEdit,value: true }
manager     permission  AllowPost+False     { key:AllowPost,value: False }
manager     permission  AllowEdit+true      { key:AllowEdit,value: true }
```

**Step 2: Group results into single row**

In SQL Server 2017+, `STRING_AGG` can be used to group the output into a single row:

```
STRING_AGG(JsonOutput, ',')
```

In the context of the SQL statement, this would look like this:

```
SELECT  Address, Type, CONCAT('[', STRING_AGG(JsonOutput, ','), ']') AS JsonOutput
  FROM  (
        SELECT  *,
                CASE
                  WHEN CHARINDEX('+', setting) > 0 THEN CONCAT('{ key:', SUBSTRING(setting, 0, CHARINDEX('+', setting)), ',value: ', SUBSTRING(setting, CHARINDEX('+', setting) + 1, LEN(setting) - CHARINDEX('+', setting) + 1), ' }')
                  ELSE ''
                END AS JsonOutput
          FROM  MyTable
        ) a
  GROUP BY Address, Type
```

Output:

```
Address     Type        JsonOutput
All.staff   permission  [{ key:AllowPost,value: true },{ key:Allowdelete,value: False },{ key:AllowEdit,value: true }]
manager     permission  [{ key:AllowPost,value: False },{ key:AllowEdit,value: true }]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and this is what I really want. But without using SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX , How can i use string_split function to cater this requirement. because i have multiple setting value which concatenate with '+' sign.  e.g providerName1+AllowPost+true or providerName2+AllowPost+true

Comment: @waruni How would the three part setting appear in the JSON?

Comment: JsonOutput look like this  [{ provider:providerName1,key:AllowPost,value: true },{ provider:providerName1,key:Allowdelete,value: False },{provider:providerName1, key:AllowEdit,value: true }]